# High Level Time Series Forecasting Question given a set of unknown data sets

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models

I have this question regarding 4 data sets where one of the data sets is missing half of the data. The data is relatively correlated, but not perfectly. How may we construct a model to produce the fourth data source’s missing data? Suppose this data is generally upward trending with seasonal cycles, as well as a large dip in 2020.

As a side note, this is a purely theoretical question and I'm just curious how other's would approach such a problem. I'm not looking for some good library to use or any complex algorithm, but rather high level reasoning for how to create a good predictor. Thank you!

Comment: So if this is a "purely theoretical question" why is pandas functionality important? In general, the best solutions involve customized code, not just a rearrangement of several library functions.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

1] Develop a [Seasonal ARIMA](http://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html) model for each of the 4 series.

2] Back out shocks (residuals) for "non-missing" days.

3] Collect shocks $(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\varepsilon_4)$ over the "non-missing" days.

4] Estimate their joint distribution function as $$
F(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\varepsilon_4) = C_{\alpha,\rho}\Bigl(F_1(\varepsilon_1),F_2(\varepsilon_1),F_3(\varepsilon_1),F_4(\varepsilon_1)\Bigr),
$$

where $C_{\alpha,\rho}()$ is some standard [Copula family](http://stanfordphd.com/Copula.html). The joint cdf implies conditional cdf $F(\varepsilon_4\, |\, \varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3)$.

5] Simulate $\varepsilon_4$ out of $F(\varepsilon_4\, |\, \varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3)$ for those days when $(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3)$ are available.